# How to globally decrease or delete the vertical spaces between lines in `alignat` and `align` environments?

Tags: align, arrays, alignat

First an MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
An example in `alignat'
\begin{alignat*}{2}
x&=3&\hspace*{1em}&why\\
&=2+1&&so\\
x&=3&\hspace*{1em}&why\\
&=2+1&&so\\
x&=3&\hspace*{1em}&why\\
&=2+1&&so.
\end{alignat*}
and an example in `align'
\begin{align*}
x&=3\\
&=2+1\\
x&=3\\
&=2+1\\
x&=3\\
&=2+1.
\end{align*}
and an example in `array'
\[
\begin{array}{rl}
x&=3\\
&=2+1\\
x&=3\\
&=2+1\\
x&=3\\
&=2+1.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the vertical spaces between lines such as `x=3` and `2+1` in `alignat` and `align` environments are bigger than those in `array` environments. Then **how to globally decrease or delete the vertical spaces between lines in `alignat` and `align` environments?**

Comment: @daleif "The spaces between lines" means the spaces between the lines such as `x=3` and ` 2+1`, not the spaces before and after the whole ones.

Comment: That was not clear. That was how I interpreted it at first, then then reacted to the other comments. I will delete my comment. As far as I know the extra spacing comes from the size of `\jot`

Comment: `array` and `align` use quite different models.

Comment: @egreg `alignat` and `align` could be page broken while `array` can't, but the spaces between lines in the former are too big.

Comment: @daleif By the way, what's your real full name and how to read it? I'd like to show thanks to you in my book.

Comment: I'm uniquely identified on the internet so you can just use google. Though thanking `daleif` is enough (note always lower case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on @daleif's comment I propose the following and hope this is close enough for you.

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%Set some lengths to zero.
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

% Save all variants into boxes to measure their heights.
\newsavebox{\alignatbox}
\savebox{\alignatbox}{%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
      \begin{alignat*}{1}%
         x&=3\\&=2+1\\x&=3\\&=2+1\\x&=3\\&=2+1.%
      \end{alignat*}%
   \end{minipage}
}
\newsavebox{\alignbox}
\savebox{\alignbox}{%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
      \begin{align*}{2}%
         x&=3\\&=2+1\\x&=3\\&=2+1\\x&=3\\&=2+1.%
      \end{align*}%
   \end{minipage}
}
\newsavebox{\arraybox}
\savebox{\arraybox}{%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
      \[%
      \begin{array}{rlll}%
         x&=3\\&=2+1\\x&=3\\&=2+1\\x&=3\\&=2+1.%
      \end{array}%
      \]
   \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
   \paragraph{An example in `alignat'.}
   height: \the\ht\alignatbox\par
   \usebox{\alignatbox}
   
   \paragraph{An example in `align'.}
   height: \the\ht\alignbox\par
   \usebox{\alignbox}
   
   \paragraph{An example in `array'.}
   height: \the\ht\arraybox\par
   \usebox{\arraybox}
\end{document}
```